# htaccess - include the query string in the redirect URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website and I want to add a code line in the .htaccess file in order to redirect automaticaly the pages to another site.

```
Redirect
/index.php/component/virtuemart/XXXXX.html
https://www.trazeras.gr/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=XXXXX
```

The XXXXX ais a number which could have 1-5 digits
The above number should be taken from the initial site url and to be used at the destination site url

I tried the following code but it doesnt work

```
# Redirect Query String
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/virtuemart/([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.trazeras.gr/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=%1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The URL doesn’t have a query string, so you shouldn’t redirect using it:

```
# Redirect Query String
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^/virtuemart/([0-9]+) https://www.trazeras.gr/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, this worked for me:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)virtuemart/([0-9]+).html$ https://www.trazeras.gr/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=$2 [R=301,L] [R=301,L]
```